# Is Netplan capable of setting link negotiation settings?

Tags: network-manager, netplan, static-ip

I set a static IP with Netplan on my desktop, but the link negotiation keeps resetting to "Ignore" every reboot on my Plasma desktop.

How can I make it permanent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**On most Desktops, folks should be adjusting all network settings, including link negotiation, using NetworkManager**. You don't specify link negotiation settings in Netplan.

For these folks, netplan file (`/etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml`) is merely a stub handing control over to NM:

```
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
```

**For folks using networkd** (usually on servers) instead of NetworkManager, you specify negotiation settings in the .link file, typically in located /etc/systemd/network/ ([reference](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.link.html)). You don't specify negotiation settings in Netplan.

> AutoNegotiation=
>
> Takes a boolean. If set to yes, automatic negotiation of transmission parameters is enabled. Autonegotiation is a procedure by which two connected ethernet devices choose common transmission parameters, such as speed, duplex mode, and flow control. When unset, the kernel's default will be used.
>
> Note that if autonegotiation is enabled, speed and duplex settings are read-only. If autonegotiation is disabled, speed and duplex settings are writable if the driver supports multiple link modes.